# Is there a difference between what is called expectimax and expectiminimax?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-theory, minimax, expectiminimax

I am a new learner of AI and I understand expectimax way of working, however, I got a new term called expectiminimax. So, does expeciminimax differ from expectimax? Or they are the same terminology?

If no, then what are the main differences between them?

Answer (score 3):

I'm still learning too, but I'll share what I've learned so far.

In simple terms they are the same, with the only difference being expectimax is for **single**-player stochastic games, while expectiminimax is for **two**-player stochastic games.

You see, expectiminimax is a variation of minimax. In minimax, there are two players, *MAX* who wants to maximize utility for itself and *MIN* who wants to minimize the utility for *MAX*. Now in stochastic games, the utility is also affected by probabilities. So in expectiminimax, *MAX* wants to maximize its **expected** utility while *MIN* wants to minimize the **expected** utility for *MAX*. One example of game where this can be used is Backgammon where there are two competing players and both roll dice.

Meanwhile, in expectimax, there is only one player, namely *MAX*. Since the outcome of its action are nondeterministic, *MAX* would want to maximize its expected utility. One example of game where expectimax is used is 2048.